# Add dropdown to graphical dialog/YAD bash script

Tags: linux, bash, pyhoca-cli

Anyone good with yad?

So basically this BASH script works fine, Debian boots into a minimal Matchbox WM environment and this script is autorun which displays a nice graphical prompt allowing entry of AD username and pass, and then the vars get passed to pyhoca-cli which logs the computer into a remote x2go-server linux terminal server.. it works without issue.

However what I want to do is add an additional drop-down selection to the YAD graphical prompt (after the first two fields), where the user can select the session (eg kde, xfce4, lxde & fluxbox), and then pass that selection to the pyhoca-cli command to replace startkde with something like start$frmdata (from the dropdown selection)...

Not sure exactly how to do this... Following is the existing code:

```
#!/bin/bash

while true; do
    frmdata=$(yad --center --undecorated --image=/usr/share/wallpaper/header-mod.jpg --image-    on-top --button="gtk-ok:0" --title "Login to Linux Terminal Server" --form --field="AD username" --field="Password:H")
    frmusername=$(echo $frmdata | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|" } { print $1 }')
    frmpassword=$(echo $frmdata | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|" } { print $2 }')

    pyhoca-cli --server some.private.ip.addr -u $frmusername --password $frmpassword -c startkde --sound none --kbd-layout us --kbd-type pc105/us -g fullscreen --add-to-known-hosts
done
```

Comment: @John Kugelman - thanks for the edit.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this...

```
frmdata=$(yad --center --undecorated --image=/usr/share/wallpaper/header-mod.jpg --image-    on-top --button="gtk-ok:0" --title "Login to Linux Terminal Server" --form --field="AD username" "" --field="Password:H" "" --field="Session:CB" "Session1!Session2!Session3")
frmsession=$(echo $frmdata | awk 'BEGIN {FS="|" } { print $3 }')
```